# php4 to php5 call of another file-php with input type is not working

Tags: php, forms, post, hidden, php4

After a change from PHP4 to PHP5 a problem occurred, I cant find it in the migration FAQ.

```
<form method='post' action='galerie.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='kategorieid' value='$id'>
<input type='hidden' name='echtkategorie' value='$kategorie'>
<input type='hidden' value='' name='geaendert'>
<input name='imageField' type='image' src='../images/bearbeiten.gif' width='39' height='40' border='0' alt='Galerie &quot;$kategorie&quot; bearbeiten'>
```

I am calling `galerie.php` with some variables `$id` and `$kategorie`, but they wont appear in the `galerie.php`:

```
$_GET['id']
```

Won’t work in `galerie.php` I do `$befehl="SELECT kategorie, id FROM $tabelle WHERE id='$kategorieid'";` but kategorieid is not there.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `method="post"` which means that you should be using `$_POST['id']` rather than `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: huh like `id = $_POST['kategorieid']`?

Comment: var_dump($_POST['kategorieid']); works, but how to use it in my code?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kategorieid']); this works dont know why

Comment: You should use it the same way you were using $_GET['id'], but with $_POST['id']. Just keep in mind that since you are getting these variables from a form, you HAVE to sanitize them, otherwise your site will be vulnerable to SQL injection and XSS. There are plenty of explanations on how to protect against these threats. `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not enough and only protect against SQL injection. Likewise, you should be using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` which is the improved version.